# JPA NamedQuery not found

Tags: sql-server, jpa, netbeans

I'm trying to get a list of persons using JPA. Every time I run the code, I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: Persoon.getAllePersonen not found."

I tried changing the table name, replaced Persoon.getAllePersonen by getAllePersonen,.... I just can't seem to figure out what's causing the error

**Persoon**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Persoon")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persoon.getAllePersonen",
            query = "SELECT p FROM Persoon p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persoon.findByName",
            query = "SELECT p FROM Persoon p WHERE p.achternaam = :persoonNaam OR p.voornaam = :persoonNaam")
})

public class Persoon implements Serializable {
```

**PersoonDao**

```
    public List<Persoon> getAlleLeden(){
            TypedQuery<Persoon> queryP = em.createNamedQuery("Persoon.getAllePersonen", Persoon.class);
                  try{ return queryP.getResultList();            
        } catch (NoResultException e){
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Cannot find leden");
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

**Generic Superclass DAO**

```
public class GenericDaoJpa<T>{

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TaijitanPU");

    protected static final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="TaijitanPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>domein.Persoon</class>
    <class>domein.Graad</class>
    <class>domein.Locatie</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\sqlexpress:1433;databaseName=Taijitan;integratedSecurity=true;"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: (1) Please post the `persistence.xml`. (2) You likely have a resource leak (do you ever close `emf`?) (3) Usually, entity managers should be created per unit of work, having a `protected static final` entity manager is not the best idea

Comment: @crizzis I've checked the possible leaks, as far as I can tell there are none. I've also added the persistence.xml code to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do an abstract class **Generic class** and override the **entityManager** of the parent class for each child. Check below. I used **EJB Stateless** for the childs.

-> PARENT DAO

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> {
...

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
```

-> CHILD DAO

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "yourPersistenceUnitName")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}
```

Comment: entityManager is in charge of Persoon, could the problem be that I'm declaring the entityManager and Factory in a generic superclass? I've added it to the edit

Comment: can I see your full **"persoon DAO class"**